# of/from several decades

Tags: usage

In the following sentence is the usage of **of** idiomatic?

> Mr. Bhat of Shopian in south Kashmir, the largest apple producing area in J&K, says he cannot betray his trade partners **of** several decades in Lucknow and Delhi. He fears the government’s offer can damage the age-old social and economic ties **the Valley have** with the rest of India.

I think in place of **of** ***from*** should be used because **from** shows **the origin of time/place**

I think there is something wrong with **have** too. Because **valley** is singular noun and hence **has** should be used in place of **have**

Comment: ***of, for, from, over, across*** (and probably others) are perfectly credible prepositions for your context. None is inherently "more correct" than any other. In BrE, superficially singular "collective group" nouns (***company, government, club***, etc.) are more likely to take a plural verb form than in AmE. Perhaps this influences the Indian English usage as cited. But much depends on whether the *target readership* think of "the Valley" as semantically equivalent to ***the people of** the Valley* (which as a Brit, I wouldn't know).

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica trade partners does not work here with from.

Answer (score 2):

One of the uses of the word "of" is to indicate the amount of time that somebody has been something. For example,

- "my wife **of** ten years" means "my wife, who has been my wife for ten years," and
- "his trade partners **of** several decades" means "his trade partners, who have been his trade partners for several decades."

As far as I know, the word "from" is not used that way.

However, there is a similar construction, the "from ... ago" construction, which has a similar meaning:

- "my classmate **from** twenty years **ago**" means "someone who was my classmate twenty years ago," and
- "his trade partners **from** several decades **ago**" would mean "some people who were his trade partners several decades ago."

---

As for "economic ties the Valley have," my guess is that "the Valley" is being used to mean "the people who live in the Valley." Sometimes, a noun that has a plural meaning takes a plural verb, even if the noun itself seems to be singular; this is especially common in British English.

Or maybe it's just a mistake, and the writer meant to write "economic ties the Valley **has**."

Comment: Yes, you explain the time frame idiom,very simply. Good.